# How to make a efficient comma separator

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table

```
create table #t(id varchar(10),value varchar(10))

insert into #t values('0001','a'),('0001','b'),('0002','c'),('0002','d')
```

I  need a efficient method of making csv

```
id    value
0001  a,b
0002  c,d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this!

```
using Stuff with xml path('')

   select id,
stuff(
(
 select ',' + value from #t t1 where t1.id=t2.id for xml path(''),type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'') from #t t2

 group by t2.id
```

Comment: You have to decode, also, the XML reserved chars. Otherwise, these chars will remain encoded: `...for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)')` (or `nvarchar(max)`).

Answer (score 0):

Hello below given requirement both columns are in VARCHAR . So we can use SUBSTRING FUNCTION and CROSS APPLY to get Expected output

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID VARCHAR(10) ,VALUE VARCHAR(10) )
INSERT INTO @t (ID,VALUE)VALUES ('0001','a')
INSERT INTO @t (ID,VALUE)VALUES ('0001','b')
INSERT INTO @t (ID,VALUE)VALUES ('0002','c')
INSERT INTO @t (ID,VALUE)VALUES ('0002','d')
INSERT INTO @t (ID,VALUE)VALUES ('0003','e')
INSERT INTO @t (ID,VALUE)VALUES ('0003','f')
SELECT  [Id], 
        SUBSTRING(d.Value,1, LEN(d.Value) - 1) VALUE
FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT [Id]
            FROM @t
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT Value + ', ' 
            FROM @t AS B 
            WHERE A.[Id] = B.[Id]
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D (Value)
```